# Centering sections

Tags: horizontal-alignment, titlesec

I would like to use `titlesec`  to center my sections as follows (MWE):

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}% command to format the section titles
        [block]% shape/type of title
        {\LARGE\bfseries}% formatting commands applied to both label and title
        {\begin{center} \thesection \end{center}}% section number; here set inside an invisible box with a constant width
        {0em}% separation between number and chapter title; we've already covered this with the box
        {}% additional formatting command for title itself not applied to number
        [
        ]%
\begin{document}
\chapter{The first chapter}
\lipsum[1-5]
\section{First section}
\lipsum[3]
\section*{Section}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

But this does not center the title of the section, and it is not very beautiful either. How can I beautifully center sections using `titlesec`?

Comment: Try `\centering` rather than `\begin{center}...\end{center}` and put it with the `\LARGE\bfseries` which applies to the title, too.

Comment: `@cfr`, I have tried, but it does not work.

Comment: My fault! I had an error in my code. Sorry for that. You should have answered it rather than comment it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will work if you put `\centering` along with `\LARGE\bfseries` as suggested by cfr.

```
\titleformat{\section}% command to format the section titles
        [block]% shape/type of title
        {\LARGE\bfseries\centering}% formatting commands applied to both label and title
        {\thesection}% section number; here set inside an invisible box with a constant width
        {1ex}% separation between number and chapter title; we've already covered this with the box
        {}% additional formatting command for title itself not applied to number
        [
        ]%
```

gives

[image]

You can also use the simplified format

```
\titleformat*{\section}{\LARGE\bfseries\centering}
```

instead of `\titleformat`.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titlesec}
%\titleformat{\section}% command to format the section titles
%        [block]% shape/type of title
%        {\LARGE\bfseries\centering}% formatting commands applied to both label and title
%        {\thesection}% section number; here set inside an invisible box with a constant width
%        {1ex}% separation between number and chapter title; we've already covered this with the box
%        {}% additional formatting command for title itself not applied to number
%        [
%        ]%

\titleformat*{\section}{\LARGE\bfseries\centering}
\begin{document}
\chapter{The first chapter}
\lipsum[1-5]
\section{First section}
\lipsum[3]
\section*{Section}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

As reminded by Bernard, you can also use `\filcenter` provided by `titlesec` instead of `\centering`.

But it would be easy to use `sectsty` as in AboAmmar's answer if possible.

Comment: Good, I in fact had an error in my code. I wrote `\titleformat{\thesection}` instead of `\titleformat{\section}`. Thank you.

Comment: @Harish Kumar: I don't know if there's any side effect with `\centering`, but titlesec provides the `\filcenter` command.

Comment: @Bernard Thanks for reminding `\filcenter`. I have added a note. BTW, there are not any side effects of `\centering` that I am aware of.

Answer (score 2):

A quick solution using the `sectsty` package

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{sectsty}

\allsectionsfont{\centering}

\begin{document}
\chapter{The first chapter}
\lipsum[1-5]
\section{First section}
\lipsum[3]
\section*{Section}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

Or, simply using `titlesec` by adding the `[center]` option as this:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[center]{titlesec}

\begin{document}
\chapter{The first chapter}
\lipsum[1-5]
\section{First section}
\lipsum[3]
\section*{Section}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That is good, but I have used `titlesec` for various other purposes in the same document. Is it not possible to adapt it to `titlesec` instead of `sectsty`?

Comment: @usr203050 Did it!