# Using center twice on a page

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I'm trying to use the \begin{center} command twice on the same page, but weirdly it's not working, the second time it gives trouble. When I take it away from the first time, then the other one does work fine. Some code of a simple case to illustrate:

```
\documentclass{report}

\begin{document}

\vspace*{2em}
\begin{center}
\section*{Abstract}
\end{center}
\noindent bla bla 

\vspace*{2em}
\begin{center}
\section*{Acknowledgements}
\end{center}
\noindent bla bla

\end{document}
```

Then the error I get is: ! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.
Which points to the second \end{center}. If I don't use centering of the first heading, but keep the centering for the second, then everything works fine.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome on TeX.SX. You are not supposed to use `\section` in a `center` environment.

Comment: Thank you! Ok, that brings me to two other questions: - Why does it work for the first section heading? How to center a section heading properly?

Comment: @Frans You can use the `titlesec` package, as explained in another question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/258459/centering-sections

Comment: but since an abstract is not really a section, you can also simply do `\newcommand*\abstractsection[1]{\begin{center}\bfseries\large #1\end{center}}` and then `\abstractsection{Abstract}`.

Comment: There's also the possibility to use `\section*{\centerline{Acknowledgements}}` outside the `\center`environment